# How to add search functionality in custom listview

Tags: android

I have a problem to add search function in a listview in my simple android app. I was followed this article [[https://workspaces.codeproject.com/vatsag/customized-android-listview-with-image-and-text][1]](https://workspaces.codeproject.com/vatsag/customized-android-listview-with-image-and-text%5d%5b1%5d), but i can't figure how to add search functionality.

This is `xparser.java`:

```
public class XParser extends DefaultHandler {

ArrayList<String> idlist = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> namalist = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> menulist = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> alamatlist = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> iconlist = new ArrayList<String>();

//temp variable to store the data chunk read while parsing 
private String tempStore    =   null;

public XParser() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

/*
 * Clears the tempStore variable on every start of the element
 * notification
 * 
 * */
public void startElement (String uri, String localName, String qName,
           Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {

    super.startElement(uri, localName, qName, attributes);

    if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("id")) {
        tempStore = "";
    } else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("nama")) {
        tempStore = "";
    } 
    else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("menu")) {
        tempStore = "";
    }
    else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("alamat")) {
        tempStore = "";
    }
    else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("icon")) {
        tempStore = "";
    }
    else {
        tempStore = "";
    }
}

/*
 * updates the value of the tempStore variable into
 * corresponding list on receiving end of the element
 * notification
 * */
public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
        throws SAXException {
    super.endElement(uri, localName, qName);

    if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("id")) {
        idlist.add(tempStore);
    } 
    else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("nama")) {
        namalist.add(tempStore);
    }
    else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("menu")) {
        menulist.add(tempStore);
    }
    else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("alamat")) {
        alamatlist.add(tempStore);
    }
    else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("icon")) {
        iconlist.add(tempStore);
    }

    tempStore = "";
}

/*
 * adds the incoming data chunk of character data to the 
 * temp data variable - tempStore
 * 
 * */
public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
        throws SAXException {
    super.characters(ch, start, length);
    tempStore += new String(ch, start, length);
}
}
```

This is BinderData.java

```
public class BinderData extends BaseAdapter {

// XML node keys
static final String KEY_TAG = "rmdata"; // parent node
static final String KEY_ID = "id";
static final String KEY_NAMA = "nama";
static final String KEY_MENU = "menu";
static final String KEY_ALAMAT = "alamat";
static final String KEY_ICON = "icon";

LayoutInflater inflater;
ImageView thumb_image;
List<HashMap<String,String>> rmDataCollection;
ViewHolder holder;
public BinderData() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public BinderData(Activity act, List<HashMap<String,String>> map) {

    this.rmDataCollection = map;

    inflater = (LayoutInflater) act
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}


public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return idlist.size();
    return rmDataCollection.size();
}

public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View vi=convertView;
    if(convertView==null){

      vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);
      holder = new ViewHolder();

      holder.tvNama = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.tvNama); // city name
      holder.tvMenu = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.tvMenu); // city weather overview
      holder.tvRMImage =(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.list_image); // thumb image

      vi.setTag(holder);
    }
    else{

        holder = (ViewHolder)vi.getTag();
    }

      // Setting all values in listview

      holder.tvNama.setText(rmDataCollection.get(position).get(KEY_NAMA));
      holder.tvMenu.setText(rmDataCollection.get(position).get(KEY_MENU));

      //Setting an image
      String uri = "drawable/"+ rmDataCollection.get(position).get(KEY_ICON);
      int imageResource = vi.getContext().getApplicationContext().getResources().getIdentifier(uri, null, vi.getContext().getApplicationContext().getPackageName());
      Drawable image = vi.getContext().getResources().getDrawable(imageResource);
      holder.tvRMImage.setImageDrawable(image);

      return vi;
}

/*
 * 
 * */
static class ViewHolder{

    TextView tvNama;
    TextView tvMenu;
    ImageView tvRMImage;
}
}
```

This is `WeatherActiviy.java`:

```
public class WeatherActivity extends Activity implements OnQueryTextListener {

// XML node keys
static final String KEY_TAG = "rmdata"; // parent node
static final String KEY_ID = "id";
static final String KEY_NAMA = "nama";
static final String KEY_MENU = "menu";
static final String KEY_ALAMAT = "alamat";
static final String KEY_ICON = "icon";

// List items 
ListView list;
EditText inputSearch;
BinderData adapter = null;
List<HashMap<String,String>> rmDataCollection;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    try {


        DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = docBuilder.parse (getAssets().open("weatherdata.xml"));

        rmDataCollection = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

        // normalize text representation
        doc.getDocumentElement ().normalize ();

        NodeList weatherList = doc.getElementsByTagName("rmdata");

        HashMap<String,String> map = null;

        for (int i = 0; i < weatherList.getLength(); i++) {

               map = new HashMap<String,String>(); 

               Node firstWeatherNode = weatherList.item(i);

                if(firstWeatherNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE){

                    Element firstWeatherElement = (Element)firstWeatherNode;
                    //-------
                    NodeList idList = firstWeatherElement.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ID);
                    Element firstIdElement = (Element)idList.item(0);
                    NodeList textIdList = firstIdElement.getChildNodes();
                    //--id
                    map.put(KEY_ID, ((Node)textIdList.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim());

                    //2.-------
                    NodeList cityList = firstWeatherElement.getElementsByTagName(KEY_NAMA);
                    Element firstCityElement = (Element)cityList.item(0);
                    NodeList textCityList = firstCityElement.getChildNodes();
                    //--city
                    map.put(KEY_NAMA, ((Node)textCityList.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim());

                    //3.-------
                    NodeList tempList = firstWeatherElement.getElementsByTagName(KEY_MENU);
                    Element firstTempElement = (Element)tempList.item(0);
                    NodeList textTempList = firstTempElement.getChildNodes();
                    //--city
                    map.put(KEY_MENU, ((Node)textTempList.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim());
                    /*
                    //4.-------
                    NodeList condList = firstWeatherElement.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ALAMAT);
                    Element firstCondElement = (Element)condList.item(0);
                    NodeList textCondList = firstCondElement.getChildNodes();
                    //--city
                    map.put(KEY_ALAMAT, ((Node)textCondList.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim());

                    //5.-------
                    NodeList speedList = firstWeatherElement.getElementsByTagName(KEY_SPEED);
                    Element firstSpeedElement = (Element)speedList.item(0);
                    NodeList textSpeedList = firstSpeedElement.getChildNodes();
                    //--city
                    map.put(KEY_SPEED, ((Node)textSpeedList.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim());
                    */
                    //6.-------
                    NodeList iconList = firstWeatherElement.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ICON);
                    Element firstIconElement = (Element)iconList.item(0);
                    NodeList textIconList = firstIconElement.getChildNodes();
                    //--city
                    map.put(KEY_ICON, ((Node)textIconList.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim());

                    //Add to the Arraylist

 rmDataCollection.add(map);
            }       
        }


        BinderData bindingData = new BinderData(this,rmDataCollection);


        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        Log.i("BEFORE", "<<------------- Before SetAdapter-------------->>");

        list.setAdapter(bindingData);

        Log.i("AFTER", "<<------------- After SetAdapter-------------->>");

        list.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

        // search
        inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.inputSearch);
        /**
         * Enabling Search Filter
         *  */
        inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                // When user changed the Text
                ((Filterable) WeatherActivity.this.rmDataCollection).getFilter().filter(cs);    
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                    int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }


            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String text = inputSearch.getText().toString().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());


            }
        });

        // Click event for single list row
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                Intent i = new Intent();
                i.setClass(WeatherActivity.this, SampleActivity.class);

                // parameters
                i.putExtra("position", String.valueOf(position + 1));

                /* selected item parameters
                 * 1.   City name
                 * 2.   Weather
                 * 3.   Wind speed
                 * 4.   Temperature
                 * 5.   Weather icon   
                 */
                i.putExtra("city", rmDataCollection.get(position).get(KEY_NAMA));
                i.putExtra("weather", rmDataCollection.get(position).get(KEY_MENU));
                i.putExtra("windspeed", rmDataCollection.get(position).get(KEY_ALAMAT));
                i.putExtra("icon", rmDataCollection.get(position).get(KEY_ICON));

                // start the sample activity
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

    }

    catch (IOException ex) {
        Log.e("Error", ex.getMessage());
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.e("Error", "Loading exception");
    }
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
    SearchManager searchManager =
           (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView =
            (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(
            searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    searchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(true);
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);


    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText)
{
 // this is your adapter that will be filtered
     if (TextUtils.isEmpty(newText))
     {
           list.clearTextFilter();
       }
     else
     {
           list.setFilterText(newText.toString());
       }

     return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 return false;
}
}
```

Comment: Your workspaces link is not reachable without account. What did you try so far to filter lists?

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/09/android-adding-search-functionality-to-listview/